# R data.table function doesn't recognize an already-specified argument

Tags: r, function, data.table

I encounter a weird problem that a `data.table` function doesn't recognize a well-defined argument if the function is used in another function.

Here is a simple example:
I get an error when the first function `testFun1`,

> `Error in fun(value) : could not find function "fun"`

However, it is clear that there is default value of `fun`.
There is no issue using `reshape2::dcast`, See `testFun2`.

```
testFun1 <- function(data, formula, fun = sum, value.var = "value") {
  data.table::dcast(data = data, formula = formula, fun.aggregate = fun,
                    value.var = "value")
}

testFun2 <- function(data, formula, fun = sum, value.var = "value") {
  reshape2::dcast(data = data, formula = formula, fun.aggregate = fun,
                    value.var = "value")
}

d <- data.table(x = c("a", "b"), y = c("c", "d"), value = 1)
testFun1(d, x ~ y)
# Error in fun(value) : could not find function "fun"
testFun2(d, x ~ y)
```

Comment: Can confirm - looking at `debug(data.table::dcast)` and `testFun1`, the `fun.aggregate` object doesn't seem to carry through properly and it goes looking for `fun()` rather than `sum()`. If you make the `testFun1` argument `fun.aggregate=sum` and update the reference in the function body too, then it starts working again. Not sure how to get it working more generally though.

Comment: it looks like this is an open issue in data.table; https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1369

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been already resolved by recent improvements to `dcast` by made Arun. They will be soon available on CRAN as 1.12.2 version.

```r
install.packages("data.table", repos="https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table")
library(data.table)
testFun1 <- function(data, formula, fun = sum, value.var = "value") {
  data.table::dcast(data = data, formula = formula, fun.aggregate = fun,
                    value.var = "value")
}

d <- data.table(x = c("a", "b"), y = c("c", "d"), value = 1)
testFun1(d, x ~ y)

testFun2 <- function(data, formula, fun = sum, value.var = "value") {
  reshape2::dcast(data = data, formula = formula, fun.aggregate = fun,
                  value.var = "value")
}

d <- data.table(x = c("a", "b"), y = c("c", "d"), value = 1)
all.equal(testFun1(d, x ~ y), as.data.table(testFun2(d, x ~ y)), check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug that had existed in a previous version of data.table, was fixed, and has popped up again.

The solution was to change the parameter name in your wrapper function from `fun` to `fun.aggregate` so that it matches the name of the `data.table::dcast` parameter.

Example:

```
testFun1 <- function(data, formula, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "value") {
  data.table::dcast(data = data, formula = formula, 
                    fun.aggregate = fun.aggregate, value.var = "value")
}
```